# How can I move the y-axis label in pgfplot so it doesn't obstruct the axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the following graph using pgfplots:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xmin=-5,ymin=-1,xmax=5,ymax=2,
    samples=100,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(ReLU(x) = max(0,x)\)},
    title={Rectified Linear Unit Function}]
\addplot[black, thick]{max(0,x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can move the y-axis label to the left hand side of the axis such that it does not obstruct the graph? I am aware I can put it on the end of the axis but then it obstructs the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! You can control the appearance of the `ylabel` with the `ylabel style` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xmin=-5,ymin=-1,xmax=5,ymax=2,
    samples=100,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(\re LU(x) = \max(0,x)\)},
    ylabel style={yshift=-0.5ex,anchor=north east},
    title={Rectified Linear Unit Function}]
\addplot[black, thick,samples at={-5,0,5}]{max(0,x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not know if it is a good idea to place the plot in an `equation*` environment, but I kept it for the moment, but I do think it is a good idea to use `\max` and `\re` for the corresponding math operators. I also use `samples at={-5,0,5}` to do the `max` function more justice.

You may want to remove the tick label at `y=2`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xmin=-5,ymin=-1,xmax=5,ymax=2,
    ytick={1},
    samples=100,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(\re LU(x) = \max(0,x)\)},
    ylabel style={yshift=-0.5ex,anchor=east},
    title={Rectified Linear Unit Function}]
\addplot[black, thick,samples at={-5,0,5}]{max(0,x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]